# How does subscript work?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

In this first picture I get the first element of the array by using:

```
subscript(array,[1],First)
```

[image: returns_one]

In this second picture I try the same but then for the second element but it gets everything from the second element to the end of the array. I just want the second element not the rest.

[image: returns_rest]

How does subscript exactly work?

Comment: I don't know much about ECLiPSe, but it looks like this boils down to what kind of term structure it sees for `[1, 9, ...]`. The fact that `[2]` yields the tail of the list implies to me that the structure is something like Prolog's list term, `'.'(H, T)` which is what is represented by the syntax `[H|T]` in Prolog. So `[2]` (which gives the second argument for the term) is yielding `T`. Just a thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @lurker says in his comment, you are trying to apply `subscript/3` to a list, but it expects an array or any other flat structure.

By convention, `ECLiPSe` uses structures with the functor `'[]'/N` for arrays. You can create them either by writing them literally

```
Array = [](5,Y,Z,9,2)
```

or by creating them with `dim/2`

```
dim(Array, [5])
```

or by converting them from a list

```
array_list(Array, [5,Y,Z,9,2])
```

On such arrays, `subscript/3` works as expected:

```
?- Array = [](5,X,Z,9,2), subscript(Array,[4],Elem).
Elem = 9
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

Note that `subscript/3` is implicitly called when you use array notation inside an arithmetic expression:

```
?- Array = [](5,X,Z,9,2), Result is Array[4] + 1.
Result = 10
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```